# new object created every time

Tags: java, android, shopping-cart

I'm developing a shopping cart app in android and a novice.  I have been facing one problem now.
I can add an item and it adds it to the cart.  I can edit the quantity of an item or remove it from the listview after I have added it to the cart.

So what I want is to disable the addToCart button if it is present in the cart already in order to avoid duplicates.  But every entry into a product is taken as a new entry.  I think I have not referenced it properly.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the Activity that gets called every time you press an item (for example: Dell inside Laptops category)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productdetails);
    LayoutInflater li;
    final List<Product> cart = ShoppingCartHelper.getCart();// get all //items from cart
    int productIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(
            ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX);// the item no in the list
    String PRODUCT_STRING = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PRODUCT");
    switch (PRODUCT_STRING) {
    case "Laptops":
        catalog = ShoppingCartHelper.getLaptopCatalog(getResources())
        break;
    case "Phones":
        catalog = ShoppingCartHelper
                .gePhonesCatalog(getResources());
        break;
    }
    final Product selectedProduct=(Product)this.catalog.get(productIndex);
// this declaration of product is taken as a new entry......................        
    ImageView productImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewProduct);

    productImageView.setImageDrawable(selectedProduct.productImage);    TextView productTitleTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductTitle);

    productTitleTextView.setText(selectedProduct.title);

    TextView productDetailsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductDetails);

    productDetailsTextView.setText(selectedProduct.description);

    final Button addToCartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonAddToCart);

    addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            cart.add(selectedProduct);
                selectedProduct.quantity ++;
            finish();
        }
    });     
    if(cart.contains(selectedProduct)) {
           addToCartButton.setEnabled(false);
           addToCartButton.setText("Item in Cart");
    }       
}
```

Comment: How do you save added items? Using database?

Comment: I think the problem here relates to the comparison between the `Product` in the cart and the 'Product` from the catalog that is performed when you do  `cart.contains(selectedProduct)`. How do you go about adding the item to the cart? Are you expecting them to be the same actual object? This seems unlikely if you are allowing a quantity to be specified. Perhaps you need to write some code to determine a match rather than let the List perform an equals comparison on the 2 objects.

Comment: Actually i assumed that the same Product can be obtained from this line       final Product selectedProduct=(Product)this.catalog.get(productIndex);                                                      i didnt use database.just a class to add items dynamically

Comment: Yes but when you add the product to.the cart what do you add and when you get the product from the catalogue what do you get. Unless you are dealing with the same actual java object.the  check for.contains will fail.e.

Comment: so what s the way to get the same object..and avoid new creation??

Comment: you do not want the same object you want another way of finding the corresponding object like using the product ID as you have not shown us your Product class we can only guess what you are trying to do. If override equals as suggested by @ridsatrio it may resolve your issue but If equals is to be used anywhere else and you do not get it right then you will have failures on your hands. also when you override equals you should also override hashcode and getting these 2 correct is known to be tricky. Try getting it generated (eclipse will do it).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest workaround to this would be to override the item's `equals()`.

Otherwise, every instance of your item will be considered (and really *is*) different from Java's perspective.

Here's how you could do it:

```
// Somewhere in your item's class..

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof YourItem)
        return false;
    YourItem i = (YourItem) o;
    // This line below is based on my assumption, you should change to better suit your usecase.
    return this.getItemId() == i.getItemId();
}
```

Of course in above code I *assume* that your item has a field for an item ID and a getter method to obtain it. Do note that it might not suit you and that you might have to make some adaptation to it.